# Skybox vs Skysphere

Tags: 3d

What are some advantages and disadvantages between the two. Especially for something like a 3D game.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Skyboxes and skyspheres are pretty much equivalent in the sense that you will get the same kind of visual effect - i.e. a nice background that appears to be at a long distance away.

However I'd normally recommend a skybox for the following three reasons:

- Less polygons required
- Assuming you set up your projection matrices correctly, you can't tell that you are inside a box (if you get it wrong, you may see some distortions)
- It's easier to render square skybox images (one for each of the size directions)

Regarding the last point, it is pretty easy to configure a renderer to produce raytraced square images that exactly fit on a skybox by creating a 90 degree field of view, e.g. in POVRay you would use something like the following:

```
camera {
   right -x
   up y
   direction -z
   location 0
}
```

I typically use 1024*1024 or 2048*2048 square textures for this.

The one good reason I can think of to use a skysphere is if you are using some kind of procedural texture approach that requires generation at (approximately) the points on a unit sphere. I think that is a pretty special case however, and unlikely to be necessary for most gaming applications.

Comment: The point about polygons is untrue - with shaders either method requires a single triangle as a minimum...

Comment: Interresting answer but it don't say if SkySphere have any advantage over SkyBox? Is there some cases where it's simply better? Maybe when you allow any rotation?

Answer (score 3):

It is easier to make textures for skybox. Also polygon count will be smaller (but this is negligible with today cards).

The only problem with skybox is that the edges of the cube may be visible under certain conditions.

Another aspect that makes a difference:

- skybox will never collide with the geometry - the image is only projected from another camera that rotates together with the user camera and is "stuck in the box"
- in case of skysphere, the background will render directly (player can "bump into the sky")

A good description and OpenGL sample is [here](http://gpwiki.org/index.php/Sky_Box).

Comment: The player shouldn't be able to bump into the sky. It's meant to stay still relative to the player!

Comment: both skybox and skysphere can be rendered at infinite distance. That solves collision with any objects in the scene.

Answer (score 3):

a skysphere is also very cool cause you can use any mercator projection map to texture it, and it have no distortion at all.

Answer (score 1):

Another advantage of skyboxes is being able to use a cubemaps for them - sphere mapping on the other hand is not hardware accelerated (afaik).

Comment: you can just render a textured sphere. That is pretty much hardware accelerated.

Comment: you need to supply uvs in that case, and transform geometry. sure that stuff is accelerated, but its not special.

the special thing about a cubemap is that the texture coordinate system is based on direction vectors - so you can just render a quad and use the view direction for the texture coordinates - no real geometry needed.

doing the same with a sphere requires converting those directions into something else - either offline by making some asset or in your pixel shader

Comment: ok I never tested to just draw a single quad and give the corners directional texture coordinates. But not always does saving polygons mean that you get performance. Honestly I think for rending just the skybox it doesn't matter at all performance wise. I still do prefer a skybox, because it has less distortion.

Answer (score 1):

when you are using a skybox, you most likely will use a box texture. This texture can also be used for reflective materials. Skyphere textures are not that easy to use here.